# How to increase the maximum billable CPU

Tags: cpu

I have 0,15 Eos in CPU in fairy wallet, so I can not delegate more Eos in CPU due to the error: "billed CPU time (857 us) is greater than the maximum billable CPU time for the transaction (165 us)" 
I think that the only way to increase my CPU is to ask somebody else to delegate 3 EOS to my Eos adress CPU. 
Can somebody help me with this?
May be you know other way?

Thanks
VB

Answer (score 0):

As of the time of this post this is a common issue. If you do not have enough EOS staked then you are frozen until network congestion clears. You will not even be able to stake more EOS to give yourself more CPU.

The only way to get your account unlocked is for another account to stake EOS on your behalf. There are few website that will do this for you for free. You can try [eosrp](https://www.eosrp.io/) from EOS New York. At the bottom they have a section for CPU Emergency

Answer (score 0):

you can use bloks.io to get 5 free transactions per day. With it u can stake more CPU and NET by your self.